# 2 Different IP Address

Tags: c#, ip-address

I have 2 methods in my program to retrieve the IP Address of the Computer.

**1st**

```
public string GetIP1()
{
    //using System.Net.Sockets;
    return Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString();
}
```

**2nd**

```
public string GetIP2()
{
    //using System.IO;
    String direction = "";
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            direction = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //Search for the ip in the html
        int first = direction.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
        int last = direction.LastIndexOf("</body>");
        direction = direction.Substring(first, last - first);
    }
    catch(Exception){ }
    return direction;
}
```

The 1st code returns an IP that looks like 10.xx.xx.x, and the 2nd code returns IP Address such as 121.xx.xx.xx

Why does the output of these two methods differ?

Comment: Do you have two different network adapters?

Comment: No WiFi adapter then. I suppose you are not developing on a notebook.

Comment: And from the first code please remove the `FirstOrDefault` and see if the second IP also comes from the collection of the first code.

Comment: yes , i have no wifi adapter...and i'm using desktop

Comment: because: http://www.whatismyip.com/why-does-wimi-show-a-different-ip-address-than-ipconfig/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you are behind some NAT.

So by running first code you're receiving your internal network address, and second code gives you real (external) IP address from which your network has access to Internet.

That's because second method is just call to external website determining your IP, and that website only can determine real IP address, not internal one.

Answer (score 2):

In the first method, you are getting the IP Address of your internal network, so if you are behind a router, you will get an internal IP address.  This is the address you would see if you ran `ipconfig /all` from a command prompt.

In the second method you are getting your internet (external) IP address.